# Android app does not start in emulator or device

Tags: android

I have finally finished my app and everything was working fine. I went back to add in the admob stuff and now it will not start in the emulator. it says it successfully installed the app on the emulator but it does not launch and the icon is not visible to try to manually run. I think the manifest is where my error is but I am unsure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Internet" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Write_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"

    ></activity>
      <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.SPLASH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.ABOUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Ship" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.OceanThunder" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Ocean" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Forest" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Rain" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Thunderbirds" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Meditation" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Focus" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Pain" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat files

```
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         
instantiate activity  
ComponentInfo{com.androidsleepmachine.gamble/com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at  
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-23 13:17:47.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
```

Comment: The logcat says that your launcher activity com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME is not present in your application.check whether you have HOME activity present inside the package com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot find a class called:

> com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME

Why is "AndroidSleepMachine" using capital letters?

Why not just use:

> android:name=".HOME"

...if your class is indeed called HOME.java? **Case-sensitivity** may be causing your issue.

`com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME` is not the same as `com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.HOME`

Comment: I changed the HOME to match the class name, Home(.java) to see if that is what the error was. I followed a tutorial for how to work in the manifest so that is why it is set up with so many issues. Also if I want the .SPLASH activity to be the one that starts first would all I need to do is replace the DEFAULT with LAUNCHER?

Comment: For the Activity that you want to have lauched from the main screen of your phone, add action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER. Get rid of the intent-filters from the other activities...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main activity name is incorrect. Java is case sensitive and your application package name is

```
package="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"
```

while your main activity class name is

```
com.AndroidSleepMachine.gamble.HOME
```

The ClassNotFoundException is being thrown because your Activity class name is incorrect in the manifest and isn't being found by the class loader.